# prepareLayout method of NSCollcectionViewLayout

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have hard time understanding the purpose of `prepareLayout` method of `NSCollectionViewLayout`.

According to the official [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionviewlayout?language=objc) it is written

> During the layout process, the collection view calls several methods of your layout object to gather information. In particular, it calls three very important methods, whose implementations drive the core layout behavior.
>
> - Use the prepareLayout method to perform your initial layout calculations. These calculations provide the basis for everything the layout object does later.
> - Use the collectionViewContentSize method to return the smallest rectangle that completely encloses all of the elements in the collection view. Use the calculations from your prepareLayout method to specify this rectangle.
> - Use the layoutAttributesForElementsInRect: method to return the layout attributes for all elements in the specified rectangle. The collection view typically requests only the subset of visible elements, but may include elements that are just offscreen.
>
> The prepareLayout method is your chance to perform the main calculations associated with the layout process. Use this method to generate an initial list of layout attributes for your content. For example, use this method to calculate the frame rectangles of all elements in the collection view. Performing all of these calculations up front and caching the resulting data is often simpler than trying to compute attributes for individual items later.
>
> In addition to the layoutAttributesForElementsInRect: method, the collection view may call other methods to retrieve layout attributes for specific items. By performing your calculations in advance, your implementations of those methods should be able to return cached information without having to recompute that information first. The only time your layout object needs to recompute its layout information is when your app invalidates the layout. For example, you might invalidate the layout when the user inserts or deletes items.

So I naively used this as a guide and rewrote my implementation of custom layout. I computed `collectionViewContentSize` and precomputed the array used in this method

```
- (NSArray<__kindof NSCollectionViewLayoutAttributes *>*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(NSRect)rect;
```

such that in all 3 required methods I just return the cached values. And after this suddenly my collectionView became extremely laggy.

Apparently the method `prepareLayout` is called on every scroll.

Can anyone clarify what does it mean. Or maybe I do not understand anything?

Comment: So what's your question? "So what is the purpose of the official documentation then" is not a real programming question; it's just a complaint. If you don't like the docs, file a bug report with Apple. Do you have a real programming problem that you can't solve? I can't believe you don't know how to stop `prepareLayout` from doing a time-consuming operation on every scroll, if that's what's happening.

Comment: It shouldn't do that unless you invalidate it somehow. Please post some code you have.

Comment: @matt Of course I changed back, such that I do not recalculate the cached values all the time. My question was not a complain, but rather the opinion of others, when do the cache values should be computed.

Comment: As the docs say, the cache values should be computed "when your app invalidates the layout." What the docs may not make quite clear at that point is that that will be every time the bounds change unless you intervene. So I do hope you'll still file a bug report on the docs if you find them misleading / inadequate.

Comment: @matt Yes I will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual thing, if you don't want `prepare` called every time there is a scroll event, is to keep a CGSize instance property and implement `shouldInvalidateLayout` so that it returns YES only if the new bounds size is different from the stored CGSize property value.

Here's a Swift example, but I'm sure you can translate it into Objective-C:

```
var oldBoundsSize = CGSize.zero
override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    let ok = newBounds.size != self.oldBoundsSize
    if ok {
        self.oldBoundsSize = newBounds.size
    }
    return ok
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this was my bad. Apparently if

```
- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(NSRect)newBounds;
```

returns YES. Then this method is called. I just changed that this method returns NO and the method `prepareLayout` has been stopped called all the time.

Comment: @matt Can you please clarify?